# Unbreakable thrown ammunition by RAW?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons, special-materials

Is there anything to make or get a thrown ammunition unbreakable? Or does something like this already exist?

I'm talking about weapons like Shurikens, Skiprock etc...

I know there is the Raptor Arrow. But it's not really what I'm looking for, since it is an arrow.

Some are talking about Riverine, or other special materials like that.  But nothing in the rules state anything about Reverine override the ammunition ruling.
Aurorum is also a special material that allow a sundered item to be put back together but it specifies "Sundered" and thrown ammunition aren't sundered, they are destroyed when they hit something.

So... Is there an obscure material, or a thrown weapon, considered an ammunition, that is not destroyed when thrown/hit something?

Comment: For context, Unbreakable Arrows appeared only in 5e, didn't exist yet in 3.x

Comment: Are you asking for *ammunition* or *thrown weapons*?

Comment: Both actually. I'm asking for weapons like Shuriken who are both thrown weapons and ammunitions for the purpose of cost etc...

Answer (score 3):

### What you're looking for does not exist.

As part of a project I'm currently working on, I recently went through every single piece of official D&D 3.0 and 3.5 media for magic items (and other things). Over 130 splatbooks and mainline modules, *Dragon* issues 274–360, *Dungeon* issues 82–154, the 3e *Polyhedron* issues, *Dragon Annual* #5 and #6, every WotC web article that was archived over the years, the five *Living Greyhawk Journal* issues that weren't part of *Dragon* or *Dungeon*, and every Living Greyhawk module I could get my hands on (293 of them, to be exact; I know for a fact that this is not all of them, but I couldn't find the rest).

With that in mind, I can confidently say: **there is no such option in 3e/3.5 D&D.**

Even major artifact and *riverine* shuriken run afoul of the "or rendered useless" clause in the ammunition rules. There is simply no indestructible, functioning thrown ammunition weapon by RAW. You will have to get a houserule from your group if you want something like that for your character.

Comment: That's a lot of material you went through. Thanks a lot for this piece of information.

Answer (score 1):

## I believe there is only one option by RAW.

Having scoured the many lists of things available to 3.5, I can only find one thing that has an anti destruction clause specifically stated.

### That would be a Major Artifact.

The general description states

> Unlike other magic items major artifacts are not easily destroyed. Each one should only have a single, specific means of destruction.

Therefore, unless the means of destruction for a given major artifact specified that it must be shot as ammunition in order to be destroyed, it cannot be destroyed regardless of what else happens to it, or other rules of the game state (unless they also apply to artifacts). Technically. This is more of an implied overrule, though so it might not be a useful option.

---

It is likely to be a little tricky to talk your DM into having a shuriken that is a major artifact, even if it had literally no other properties whatsoever... just the indestructible quality may give most DMs pause.

---

If an artifact is not an option, then I am not aware of any indisputable RAW method to obtain unbreakable ammunition.

Comment: Major artifacts can't easily be destroyed, but that doesn't mean everything that isn't easily destroyed is automatically a major artifact. It's a square/rectangle situation. If you're homebrewing a pile of reusable shurikens, they wouldn't need to be a major artifact.

Comment: The original question asked for RAW, not homebrew. Thus all homebrew are not valid. By the rules, the only unbreakable thing in the 3.x game are major artifacts, which by definition can only be destroyed using a unique singular method... and thus is implied unbreakable by any other means, which theoretically includes ammunition rules. An unsatisfactory answer, in my opinion, but that is what is in the rules. I would be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: Unless there's a printed major artifact that's a reusable piece of ammunition, you'd be homebrewing a custom major artifact, though.

Comment: Anything created using the magic item creation rules is by definition not homebrew. **Obviously therefore, since the rules on creating artifacts are severely lacking, I think you have a valid point.** But nonetheless, the major artifacts are the closest rule to unbreakable in 3.x by RAW, and as silly as it seems, the best answer this question is likely to get?

Comment: There are no magic item creation rules for artifacts as far as I know; they even explicitly say "the secrets of creating artifacts are long lost." That said, I do agree that there don't seem to be any alternatives with rules backing.